# Add git repository to github subdirectory

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a directory `lessons`, then under it subdirectories `20200110`, `20200111`, `20200112` etc. Each of the subdirectories contain lesson files. I want this directory structure on my github site just like it is on my computer. How can I do this? When I do `git init` inside, say, `20200110`, add, commit, etc., the next step is to do `git remote add origin remote repository URL`, however, I can't figure out what that remote repository URL is supposed to be. What am I missing? Again, I need to do this for each day's lessons.

Answer (score 0):

Login into `github`, create your empty repo on https://github.com/new, and then you can see the guidelines to push the directories into repo URL.

Answer (score 0):

Git tracks only files not directories. Directories are only added to complete paths to files they contain. That is, directories `20200110`, `20200111` and `20200112` inside your git repository `lessons` will each be tracked as soon as it contains a file. It's not really a directory being tracked but a file inside.
You may check the link [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository).

Comment: Actually, when I created `lessons/20200110/file1.txt` the offered clone URL was only `.../lessons/` and not `.../lessons/20200110`.

Comment: what is the output of your `git status`?

Comment: Well, the clone `url` only reflects the repository name not its directory structure. Check if you are cloning the right branch in case you have multiple branches and you changes happen to be in a non-default branch. You may try `git clone --branch <BRANCH_NAME> <CLONE_URL>` to clone a specific branch. Alternatively you may try merging your branch into default branch (master by default) which git clones if no `--branch` option is specified.